# how to insert html tags into sql database using c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

i want insert html tags as string it to sql table from a text box. When i got normal insert query, i got the error like,

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client `(Res_Details="<h2>Anotherone</h2>").`

**Description:**

ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it.

For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874.

Comment: The link it provides (that you pasted here) contains **everything you need to know** about this error. It also gives you a few methods to stop it from happening.

Comment: are you using asp.net or asp.net mvc?

Comment: Why would you want to insert the data with html tags? If it is for formatting purposes, you can append the html tags during the display after you query from the database. Otherwise, the link you have provided explains everything.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297679/A-potentially-dangerous-Request-Form-value-was-det check this out it may helps u a lot..

Comment: i just want to know how it explicitly allow this

Comment: Have you looked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)??

Comment: @user2586070 I suggest you read the article that the error tells you to.

Answer (score 3):

Put `[ValidateInput(false)]` above your Post action.

Alternatively put `[AllowHtml]` above the required property.

**Do not** do as other users have suggested and put `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` into your `web.config` as this is, to quote Microsoft, **"the least secure way to disable request validation."**

[See this MSDN post for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx#code-snippet-6)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to my web.config under the system.web tag solved the same problem I experienced:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" ValidateRequest="false"%>
```

Add the validateRequest="false" in your .aspx page.

if this doesnt work try

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
<system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[AllowHtml]` on your `view model property`  should resolve your problem

Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

This is a useful solution if you want to use `editors` for `textareas`.